# Can't run program with ProcessBuilder, runs fine from command line

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder

On linux (debian), I can run this command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java -jar ~/myjar.jar ".*"
```

I am trying to run it from a Java program instead with:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(java, "-jar", "~/myjar.jar", "\".*\"");
```

`System.out.println(pb.command());` prints the following, as expected:

```
[/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java, -jar, ~/myjar.jar, ".*"]
```

However I don't get the same output from the program (it runs but the ouput looks as if the `".*"` argument is not properly taken into account).

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

*Note: the same code works fine on Windows.*

Comment: Do not Use ProcessBuilder heavily, because it is not stable, very easily to fail for command with complex output like 'mvn build'. Use the shell script instead in case possible

Comment: @Amos I regularly use ProcessBuilder for commands with large output without any problems, as long as the process stream is consumed - I don't really know what stability issues you are referring to.

Comment: Hello assylias , Earlier we were using ProcessBuilder to run mvn (maven) commands, and it is usually get stuck and the ProcessBuilder stops there forever

Comment: @Amos the likeliest reason is that you are not consuming the output stream of the Process in a timely fashion. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16983563/829571

Comment: Hello assylias,  thanks a lot for the info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the wildcard character is not being expanded using a [glob](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_glob.htm). You can use a shell instead:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = 
       new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "java -jar ~/myjar.jar \".*\"");
```

or you can remove the double-quotes around the wildcard:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(java, "-jar", "~/myjar.jar", ".*");
```

Answer (score 0):

For. e.g. to get all the cpu frequency in Android.

`ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
p.command("/system/bin/sh","-c","cat sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq ");`