# Node.js: Process Spawn Hang

Tags: node.js, shell, process, stdout, spawn

I am trying to run the following shell command:

`netstat -nat | grep 3000`

and eventually

`netstat -nat | grep 3000 | grep ESTABLISHED`

from Node.js to obtain ip address connected to specific port using `spawn` according to https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options visible below:

```
const netStat = spawn('netstat', ['-nat']);
const grep = spawn('grep', ['3000']);

netStat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  grep.stdin.write(data);
});

console.log('Determining public ip\'s connected to port 3000');
grep.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

But the result just hangs, am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Handle all the events, probably missing stuff from `stderr`?

Comment: Why is that, that you have to handle all the events? - It worked

Comment: Not saying you _have_ to, sorry --- it was more of a statement on "hopefully this will show you why it's failing", but I'm glad it fixed your error LOL  --- What node version are you running?

Comment: Lol, well whatever I''ll just leave it then I guess

Comment: My guess is that it can't open anything to pipe output to stderr so it just continues trying forever

Comment: Interesting, makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't read from the `stderr` pipe and don't ignore `stdio` using the options, the process hangs because the pipe is still open until read from.

A similar, but unrelated issue is [Why is my Node child process that I created via spawn() hanging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792427/why-is-my-node-child-process-that-i-created-via-spawn-hanging) .